# Turning points of a Bezier curve

Tags: calculus, parametric

I would like to find those points where a [Bezier curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) $\mathbf{C} = [(t(u) , P(u)]^T$ has zero gradient. Following the chain rule, I have tried the following

$$
\frac{dP}{dt} = \left( \frac{dP}{du} \right)  \left( \frac{dt}{du} \right)^{-1}
$$

The trouble is that setting $\frac{dP}{du}$ to zero imples that $\frac{dt}{du}$, or more specifically $\mathbf{t}(u)$ plays no part in the determining the turning point(s) -- and that I find highly unusual.

Is my thinking right?

Comment: Erm... What is $u$? (or, rather, what is $t(u)$?)

Comment: A Bezier curve is a parametric curve. $u$ is the parameter.

Comment: Correct. So, what is $t(u)$? then?

Comment: It has the same form as $P(u)$. Take a look at the Quadratic and Cubic Bézier curves on the Wikipedia page, and replace $\mathbf{B}(u)$ by $t(u)$ or $P(u)$. $\mathbf{B}(u) = [ t(u) , P(u)]^T$. But it won't matter if $\frac{dt}{du}$ plays no part in determining the turning point of $\mathbf{B}(u)$.

Comment: I don't understand the question, either. A Bezier curve is a mapping from an interval (usually $[0,1]$) into $\mathbb R^2$ or $\mathbb R^3$. Best expressed as $t \mapsto (x(t),y(t))$ or $t \mapsto (x(t),y(t), z(t))$. How does this relate to your notation? Is your "$P$" a number or a point in $\mathbb R^2$? Why do we have two parameters ($u$ and $t$)?

Comment: Another very unhelpful word is "gradient". Normally, it is real valued functions of several variables that possess gradients. Here the situation is quite opposite. I hope that what bubba wrote in his answer is what you meant, but if so, he has made a very good job of mind-reading...

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I'm interested in a Bezier curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$, where $u$ is the parameter in the range $[0,1]$. Also, by gradient I mean derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conventional expression for a Bezier curve is 
$$
\mathbf P(t) = (1-t)^3\mathbf P_0 + 3t(1-t)^2\mathbf P_1 +3t^2(1-t)\mathbf P_2 + t^3\mathbf P_3
$$
Or, writing this out component-wise (assuming a 2D curve):
$$
x(t) = (1-t)^3x_0 + 3t(1-t)^2x_1 +3t^2(1-t)x_2 + t^3x_3 \\
y(t) = (1-t)^3y_0 + 3t(1-t)^2y_1 +3t^2(1-t)y_2 + t^3y_3
$$
The gradient $dy/dx$ will be zero when $dy/dt$ is zero. The expression for $x(t)$ is irrelevant in this computation. It sounds like that's what's bothering you. But it should make sense -- the curve's movement in the $x$-direction is not related to its movement in the $y$-direction.